# In this example, should I use WebSocket or HTTP?

Tags: performance, http, websocket, architecture

I have an intuition (maybe wrong) that would be better to use WebSocket in a specific process in my application. First, I need to know if I'm right, after, how I could measure the performance in the two options. I would be grateful if someone could share some thoughts.

I load all the user's orders to the dashboard after the login.

I built the Server API in graphQl, so I query the resolver to get the orders and display them.

Whenever the customer creates a new order, I add it to the database, redo the query on the frontend, and reload all the orders with the new one on the array. So the dashboard is updated.

However, I've been thinking that maybe, pushing the new order data to the preexistent order array (saved on the state - React) would be more efficient. When a customer creates an order, I emit (via Websocket) the new order data, the dashboard listens to the event and pushes to the state.

Am I right?

Comment: Don't use websockets. Reserve that for near real-time, frequent updates.
Orders are rarely made so WS would be an overkill.

Comment: Great! It makes perfect sense. Even if it's more efficient, I will barely execute this process. So no need for complexity.